# How to access nested Obj in react?

Tags: reactjs, json, object

Why some attributes inside this weather Obj are accessable(first layer), but second layer cannot be accessed? See below [picture](https://openweathermap.org/weather-data) for Obj.

with these code:

```
const Weather=(props)=>{
        const{capital, api_key} = props
        const [weather, setWeather] = useState('')
        useEffect(() => {
            axios
            .get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${capital}&units=metric&appid=${api_key}`)
            .then(response => {
                setWeather(response.data)
            })
        }, [])
        console.log('weather', weather)
        
        
        return(
            <div>
                <div> temperature {weather.visibility} Celcius</div>
                <img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03n@2x.png' alt="flag" width="120" height="100"></img>
                <p>wind {weather.main.temp} m/s</p>
            </div>
            
        )
    }
```

I can access e.g.,{weather.visibility}, but not {weather.main.temp}. Do you know why is it the case?

[image]

Comment: you have to post the real json, not picture if you want to get  real help.

Comment: For what it’s worth, api key and city are dependencies of your useEffect. If you do t add them, you’ll be back here later with another question

Comment: The only reason weather.visibility isn’t breaking is because you’ve initialized weather to a string (why?) and the visibility property of a string is undefined (but doesn’t cause an error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with your url, also on the first render `weather.main.temp` is undefined, because the api request is async code. The code below is working here:

```
const Weather=(props)=>{
    const{capital, api_key} = props;
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState('');
  
    useEffect(() => {
      axios
      .get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${capital}&appid=${api_key}`)
      .then(response => {
          setWeather(response.data)
      })
    }, [])
    console.log('weather', weather)
    
    
    return(
        <div>
            <div> temperature {weather.visibility} Celcius</div>
            <img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/03n@2x.png' alt="flag" width="120" height="100"></img>
            <p>wind {weather?.main?.temp} m/s</p>
        </div>
        
    )  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Care to share what is the format "?.", first time I see this style.